# Why is different function used for the derivative of sigmoid than its true derivative?

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

Sorry for the long title but why do I always see in the example code that the derivative of sigmoid is x * (1 - x). While the true mathematical derivative is s(x) * (1 - s(x)) and in fact, I tried to change the derivative in the code to its true mathematical derivative but it didn't even converge so I guess maybe that's why. But then how did it comes to x * (1 - x) instead of the real one? could someone please explain this to me?

Here's the code (from i am trask's blog [link here](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/)):

```
X = np.array([ [0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1] ])
y = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,4)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((4,1)) - 1
for j in xrange(60000):
    l1 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(X,syn0))))
    l2 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(l1,syn1))))
    l2_delta = (y - l2)*(l2*(1-l2))
    l1_delta = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T) * (l1 * (1-l1))
    syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
    syn0 += X.T.dot(l1_delta)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at [tensorflow's implementation of the gradient of the sigmoid](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/math_grad.cc#L228):

```
Status SigmoidGrad(const AttrSlice& attrs, FunctionDef* g) {
  return GradForUnaryCwise(g, {
      {{"y"}, "Sigmoid", {"x"}},
      FDH::Const("const", 1.0f),
      {{"one"}, "Cast", {"const"}, {{"SrcT", DT_FLOAT}, {"DstT", "$T"}}},
      {{"a"}, "Sub", {"one", "y"}, {}, {"dy"}},
      {{"b"}, "Mul", {"y", "a"}},             // y * (1 - y)
      {{"dx"}, "Mul", {"dy", "b"}},           // dy * y * (1 - y)
  });
}
```

As you *can* see, the implementation is `s(x) * (1 - s(x))`. Note that they reuse the output of the sigmoid itself `y = s(x)`, therefore they write `y * (1 - y)`. Maybe in your example they did the same and that's the source of the confusion.

**UPDATE**: OP has included the blog that is the source of the confusion. There, we can see that function `nonlin` is misleading:

```
# sigmoid function
def nonlin(x, deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return x*(1-x)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
```

It is misleading because argument `x` means different things depending on the value of flag `deriv`, and there is no comment in the code indicating so. If `deriv` is `False`, then `x` is the input of the sigmoid. If `deriv` is `True`, `x` is the sigmoid of the input. We can deduce it from its usage in the code. Here the author uses `nonlin` to compute the sigmoid: `l1 = nonlin(np.dot(l0,syn0))`; and here the author uses `nonlin` to compute its derivative: `nonlin(l1,True)`. As you can see, in the second case the author supplies `l1` as input to `nonlin`, and `l1` is the output of the previous invocation to `nonlin`, that is, `l1` is the sigmoid of the input.

Comment: I'd like to see the original author take their `nonlin` function into https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . . . :-)